# npm install express isn't working still

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I entered "sudo npm install -g express-generator" which threw errors back at me.

I then checked issues like this on Stackoverflow and found none were successful.

The things I tried were:

"sudo chown -R username ~/.npm" and "npm cache clean"
but it's throwing an error back:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" 
"express-generator" "-g"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! uid must be an unsigned int
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-   g" "express-generator"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue with node 6.6.0 and npm 3.10.8. Have you tried downgrade to 3.10.3?

```
npm install -g npm@3.10.3
```

or updating node?